# How to display a map function from a fetch REACT.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

This is my first time using this website so bear with me...
I am trying to display an array of 10 youtube videos from a playlist using the youtube api. So far I am able to console.log the json data from the api. Although the issue arrives when I attempt to display that json data in my react app using  inside a map function.

Here is all my code :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import './Videos.css';
import VideosCP from '../Pages/VideosPage/VideosSearch'
import youtubeSearch from "../../api/youtubeSearchApi";
import VideosList from "../Pages/VideosPage/VideoList";

const YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST_ITEMS_API = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems';

let url = `${YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST_ITEMS_API}?part=snippet&playlistId=myPlaylistId&maxResults=10&key=myYoutubekey`

function Demo() {
    
}

class Videos extends Component{

    state = {
        videoMetaInfo:[],
        selectedVideoId: null
    }

    onVideoSelected = videoId => {
        this.setState({
            selectedVideoId:videoId
        })
    }

    onSearch = async keyword => {
        const response = await youtubeSearch.get("/search",{
            params:{
                q:keyword
            }
        })
        console.log(this.state);

        this.setState({
            videoMetaInfo: response.data.items,
            selectedVideoId: 'Nl3DoewG3Co'
        })
    }

    playlistRender = async () => {
        const data =  await fetch(url);
        let commits = await data.json();
        console.log('data', commits)

    }

    render(){

        const Data = ({data}) => {
            data = this.playlistRender()
            const results = data.items.map((item)=>{
                const {id, snippet = {}} = item
                const title = snippet
                return(
                    <li key={id}>
                        <h3>{title}</h3>
                    </li>
                )
            });
            return results
        }

        return(

            <div className="wrapper">
                <div className="wrapper-inner scroll">
                    <VideosCP onSearch={this.onSearch}/>
                    <VideosList onVideoSelected={this.onVideoSelected}
                    data={this.state.videoMetaInfo}/>
                    <ul>
                       <Data/>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Videos
```

The code compiles fine in the terminal but once inside the browser it spits the error : "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined".

Hence, the error is caused by this line which states : `data.items.map((item)=>{`

What's even more weirder is that the console in the browser recognizes that there is an "items" in the array. Why is the browser spitting this error at me? Can it not map the items? If so why not? And how is this error fixable?

I have tried everything so far and this is the closest I've gotten but yet no results.

Please help me, stack overflow is my only hope...

Comment: there are so many things that I don't understand:
your "playlistrender" method doesn't return any data but you try to assign data variable in your Data component in the render() method. Why define a data argument for your Data component. And most importantly you can expect to render if your data in your component state. Otherwise, you need to force your component to update. 
You should read some articles about state and class component life cycles.

Comment: I got very desperate and attempted various nonsense fixes. But up to this point I get a TypeError: this.state.commits.map is not a function

Comment: take a little break when you feel stressed or desperate. :)
After your break, first, check your API URL if is it correct try it with the postman to validate if is it returns data. Maybe your API call didn't return data or throw an error. Because you don't have any exception handler block.

Comment: But my api does return data https://imgur.com/a/pFvHW9x idk if this counts :/

Comment: The issue has been resolved :)

Comment: Happy for you. :) But again, reading React components lifecycles and state mechanism will be good for you. And of course, give a break. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data you're loading from the API is stateful, so you'll want to set it to state once it's loaded. Then, you can map over this stateful information once it exists.

I also added a `componentDidMount` method call to make sure we call the API once the component mounts.

```
class Videos extends Component{

    state = {
        videoMetaInfo:[],
        selectedVideoId: null,
        commits: []
    }

    onVideoSelected = videoId => {
        this.setState({
            selectedVideoId:videoId
        })
    }

    onSearch = async keyword => {
        const response = await youtubeSearch.get("/search",{
            params:{
                q:keyword
            }
        })
        console.log(this.state);

        this.setState({
            videoMetaInfo: response.data.items,
            selectedVideoId: 'Nl3DoewG3Co'
        })
    }

    playlistRender = async () => {
        const data =  await fetch(url);
        let commits = await data.json();
        this.setState({ commits });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.playlistRender();
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="wrapper">
                <div className="wrapper-inner scroll">
                    <VideosCP onSearch={this.onSearch}/>
                    <VideosList onVideoSelected={this.onVideoSelected}
                    data={this.state.videoMetaInfo}/>
                    <ul>
                        {this.state.commits.map((item) => {
                            const {id, snippet = {}} = item
                            const title = snippet
                            return (
                                <li key={id}>
                                    <h3>{title}</h3>
                                </li>
                            )
                        })}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Videos
```

Comment: +1, You can remove the `destructuring` in your `Data` component, nothing is passed as a `prop` or if anything would be passed `this.playListRender()` overwrites that, which returns a `Promise<undefined>`. So I believe you can remove the whole `Data` component from `render` since there is `no` implementation in your example.

Comment: Greetings op here,

I tried your fix but it just ends up with "TypeError: this.state.commits.map is not a function"...

Thank you tho

Comment: I assumed that whatever is returned from the API call is an array, but if it's not you'll have to figure out how to massage it into the format you need.

Comment: That's the weird part, the api does returns a valid array in which I am trying to map the "items" from that array... yet my code refuses to map it :/ I feel like I am getting close to a fix tho.

Comment: And you're definitely initializing `commits` in state to an empty array?

Comment: This is what the console gives me https://imgur.com/QcJQQVm the items are definately there from the screenshot so i know they exist.

Comment: So it might need to be `{ commits: commits.items }` or possibly `{ commits: commits.data.items }`

Comment: I assume that this new sugestion would be to add it to `commits.items` or `commits.data.items` where the `this.setState({ commits });` line is. I tried both and here is what i get : `commits.items`  gives me `Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {publishedAt, channelId, title, description, thumbnails, channelTitle, playlistId, position, resourceId}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead` and `commits.data.items` gives me : `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'items' of undefined`

Comment: Ah ha, we're getting close! So it's almost certainly `commits.items`. Now it's complaining because `title` isn't a string, it appears to be an object. So you'll likely want to change `const title = snippet` to `const { title } = snippet` since `snippet` appears to have a bunch of different properties.

Comment: Houston we have lift off! https://imgur.com/a/4AfokWO